Can I charge an EV at 16 Amps on a 20 Amp circuit with 15 Amp outlets?
I have an electric motorcycle (96-volt, 64Ah battery) that came with an external charger (with a regular plug) with the following specs:
Power rating: 3300 watts

Current rating: 16 amps

100% of the electrical outlets in my house look like 15amp outlets, meaning none of them have the "T" in them like 20amp outlets do. But when I look at the breaker box 80% of them have a 20amp fuse. Is it possible that some of the 15amp outlets are really 20amp outlets? But then why do they not look like 20amp outlets? Even the fridge is plugged into a non "T" outlet.
And another question I have is is it OK to charge the motorcycle with a 15amp outlet? The charger is 16amps so it's just one amp over.
Finally, can I use this charger as an extension cord? Because I also need a slight extension on the charger (it only has like a 3 foot cable).
I would plug the Evdance into an outlet and then plug in the motorcycle charger into it, but in that case wouldn't there be two chargers charging the motorcycle?
This all sounds very complicated because no where in the manual does it state you need a 20amp outlet to use the 16amp charger and so I thought I could just plug it into any outlet.
I would appreciate any advice.
Also, here is some info I found from the website on the charger:
"The charger is separate from the motorcycle and can be plugged into any standard 110-volt outlet in the US. It has a power rating of 3300 watts and a current rating of 16 amps. It weighs about 15 lbs and has a sturdy design that makes it durable and reliable."
So it's OK to use any household outlet?


Can use 15 amp receptacles on a 20 amp circuit as long as it not a single one(most are duplex).  About the only thing you need to check is the wire gauge.  You must have 12 gauge wire on 20 amp circuits.

OP also needs to confirm which outlets are on 20A circuit breakers.  If any 20A breakers have 14g wire, they must be swapped out for 15A breakers.

Please ask just one question per post. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Where did this motorcycle and battery charger come from?  You can't get 3300 watts at 16 amps from normal 120V US power.  It would need an ~208V supply to have that wattage/amperage rating.  A picture of the charger nameplate would be helpful to identify exactly what you have.

Machavity's answer is perfect regarding a pure 120V 15A vs. 20A issue. 16A is 80% of 20A, so that is the NEC maximum for continuous usage (like EV battery charging) on a 20A circuit. If you simply had a 20A 120V device with an improper 5-15 plug, this would be the solution.
But there is a MUCH BIGGER PROBLEM. 3300W at 16A is 206V. Which means this charger is likely designed for a 200+V installation - either 240V in the US/Canada, 208V in the US (common in large buildings) or anywhere from 220V to 250V in most other parts of the world.
With small electronics - laptop or desktop computer, monitor, inkjet printer (but not usually laser printer), TV, etc. it is quite common to have a power supply which can handle a wide range of voltage - e.g, 100V to 250V and frequency - 50 Hz/60 Hz. That power supply will automatically and safely adjust to provide the desired output voltage (typically 5V to 20V but depends on the device) and everything works just fine.
However, there are two types of loads that simply don't work that way:

Large motor loads - that's why you generally can't easily convert large power tools (table saw, dust collector, etc.) or motorized appliances (washing machine, vacuum cleaner) from 120V to 240V or vice versa. There are some exceptions, but typically those are on relatively expensive power tools and converted by moving power wires on the motor.
Large resistive loads - water heaters, space heaters, etc. For these frequency is generally not an issue but using the wrong voltage can result in burning things up (120V device on 240V power) or really poor performance (240V device on 120V power).

Battery charging gets interesting. On a really advanced system, including most EVs with large batteries and sophisticated battery charging/management - Tesla, Rivian, etc. but actually any EV made by any major manufacturer (Ford, GM, BMW, etc.) the EV itself handles different voltages - 120V AC and 240V AC but also DC up to 400V or even 800V or more, depending on the model.
However, what you have here appears to be a much more basic system. Presumably it is designed to convert ~240V AC into an appropriate DC voltage for charging the battery. If you feed it 120V instead of 240V it could:

Run at ~ 1650W and overload a 15A 120V circuit but be perfectly safe on a 20A circuit. Note that this will likely cut the charging speed to about half of what is listed in the advertising materials for the charger/double the time to charge.
Not work at all. Really.
Attempt to pull as much as ~ 3300W and trip a breaker (hopefully!) pretty quickly.
Run at somewhat lower than 1650W and charge even more slowly.

The bottom line is that a device sold in the US with a 16A rating and a 15A cord/plug is simply wrong. And there is no easy way to know how many other things might be wrong:

Wires too small
Unsafe design that could lead to exposed 120V AC
Unsafe design leading to over-charging of batteries
etc.


UPDATE
OP provided a link for the charger which led me to the manual for the motorcycle. On page 35 it says:

Charger - External charger AC220V, output current 15A

which basically confirms what I thought: this is designed for 220V charging. Now the US, for far longer than EVs have been a big thing, has been a 120V/240V country. But the terminology persists. And it is likely that if it is designed for nominal 220V that it will work perfectly fine on the full range from 208V (some, mostly large, buildings) to 240V (most single-family homes). But that does not mean it will work well at 120V.
ASK THE MANUFACTURER what voltage range and current parameters actually apply to this charger.

That is a good point about 208 volts. I couldn't make it work with 240v, so I discounted it.

For starters, 15A outlets are normal on a 20A circuit

A 15A outlet is rated for 15A, with a 20A pass through. That is to say that the 20A circuit is in continuance throughout the circuit, however the receptacle itself (the contacts) are rated for 15A continuously. Any single appliance with a 15A plug will not normally draw more than 80% of 15A, or 12A. The total circuit draw (multiple appliances - same circuit) can be 20A before the breaker trips.

Obviously, a 16A device will have a 20A plug.
It's odd that they would have such a high draw. 20A plugs are uncommon in households. Most EVs will accept 13A @ 120v for that reason.
The Amazon link shows a device that has a 5-20 plug with a 5-15 adapter. What appears to be the manual (the model has an extra letter, but looks to be the same) says it accepts 16A OR 12A. The confusing part is it doesn't say how it tells the difference between the two. Is there a switch? Some sort of auto-sense? A mechanism on a 5-15 adapter? The company is Chinese and they're dodgy on the UL rating question.

And another question I have is is it OK to charge the motorcycle with a 15amp outlet? The charger is 16amps so it's just one amp over.

Don't bet the farm on this. The risk here is starting an electrical fire. I'm leery of anything that wants to use more electricity than a device is designed for.
The fix
The good news is there's a safe and easy solution here. You'll need to do some work first.

Turn the breaker off for the outlet you want to plug into. It should be a 20A breaker.
Remove the covering plate and unscrew the outlet from the box.
Check the wire size by removing one of the wires from the outlet. Easiest way is to use a wire stripper. The wire should fit the 12 gauge hole (unless you have aluminum wire, in which case you have a different problem).

12 gauge wire is suitable for 20A circuits. At this point, you're now set to do the next step: go buy a NEMA 5-20 outlet (probably just listed as a 20A outlet). Buy the premium one if you can (has a brass self-grounding plate on the bottom screw, like this one). Now, just remove the old outlet and put your new one in.
Assuming there's not much else on the circuit, you should be just fine to use your 16A charger now without modification. This shouldn't cost you more than a few bucks for the outlet and your time.

I would assume the Chinese-made Amazon/Temu/whatever device is not UL listed, period.

As for your question about using an extension cord. Yes, you can but you need to get a 12-gauge cord (look for a “12/3” designation), keep it as short as possible and completely uncoil the cord when in use (if you leave it coiled, it could overheat).
Many appliances advise not to use an extension cord because people try to use a cheap 16-gauge cord and it burns up. Better to say no then to be sued when a cheap cord starts a fire.
